# While I click on Recycler view item inside alert dialog it shows Error: Activity has leaked window DecorView@1ac0c00[] that was originally added here

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-alertdialog

```
 public class WelcomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    {
        Button language;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            language = (Button) findViewById (R.id.btn_language);
            language.setOnClickListener(new View . OnClickListener () {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater . from (WelcomeActivity.this);
                    final View languageDialogView = factory.inflate(R.layout.language_dialog, null);
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(WelcomeActivity.this);
                    builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.select_language));
                    builder.setView(languageDialogView);

                    RecyclerView recycler_language =(RecyclerView) languageDialogView . findViewById (R.id.recycler_language);
                    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(WelcomeActivity.this);
                    recycler_language.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

                    alertDialog = builder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When i Click on item in recyclerview it crashes and show error android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity in.co.websites.websitesapp.common.WelcomeActivity has leaked window DecorView@1ac0c00[] that was originally added here

Is there anything I have missed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Activity has leaked window that was originally added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added)

Comment: How should I implement this because I'am not able to do, I just wanted the dialog should get dismiss, but it crashes

Comment: Where do you set an adapter for recycleView? and when you run this code everything works you can scroll this list ? but it crashes when you clicked ?